# Delaying Rx-java Observable until another Observable completes

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java

It's a beginner's question. I am writing a unit test and I need to make `a` observable starting after `b` completed.

```
Observable<Integer> a = Observable.just(3, 4);
Observable<Integer> b = Observable.just(1, 2);

// TODO code needed here

// It is a is unit test above the line
// ---------------------------
// below is the code of the class being tested

a.forEach(System.out::print);
b.forEach(System.out::print);
```

What should be the code to have

```
1234
```

printed out?

I tried `concatWith()`, `toBlocking()` and nothing seems to work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you use `concatWith`? It should be `b.concatWith(a).forEach(System.out::print)`. You can also use `a.startWith(b).forEach(System.out::print)`.

Comment: This creates a single observable. In my case I have two separate subscribers, as presented in the original question. The only thing I can change is how I construct observables. So I can add only some code in the place indicated by ToDo. Other words, dont take my code literally. The goal is not to print 1234, but to synchronize observables (like stated in the title).

Comment: @LukaszGuminski - There is no code whatsoever that you can place in the `// TODO` that will change the how the two subscriptions will the run. You must also be able to change the two subscriptions also. It other words, in the to-do section you'll need to map `a` to `a2` and `b` to `b2` and then finally subscribe to `a2` and `b2`. Is that something you can do?

Comment: Yes, i can do it. I updated the original question to indicate where is the code of test case I am writing. Below is the class I cannot change.

Comment: @LukaszGuminski - Don't forget the `@` notification to get someone's attention.

Comment: @LukaszGuminski - So what you're saying is that the code `a.forEach(System.out::print); b.forEach(System.out::print);` cannot change? Can I change `Observable<Integer> a = Observable.just(3, 4); Observable<Integer> b = Observable.just(1, 2);`?

Comment: @Enigmativity Correct. You cannot change subscriptions. In reality these are sequences of various types (not integer). The class being tested performs multistage operations. It takes events from first stream, processes them, and then waits for events from another stream. To test it properly i need to block second sequence until first is processed. The question aimed just to isolate the problem and present it in a very simple way..

Comment: @LukaszGuminski - You didn't answer my second question. Can I change `Observable<Integer> a = Observable.just(3, 4); Observable<Integer> b = Observable.just(1, 2);`?

Comment: @Enigmativity `a` needs to emit `3` and `4`. `b` needs to emit `1` and `2`. But it doesn not need to be through `just`. The code is is my test case, so I can emit the values a different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apologize, but I'm a C# developer and not Java at all.

Here's one way to do it in C#. I assume it can be easily transcoded:

```
IObservable<int> a0 = new [] { 3, 4 }.ToObservable();
IObservable<int> b0 = new [] { 1, 2 }.ToObservable();

var a = new Subject<int>();
var b = b0.Finally(() => a0.Subscribe(a));

a.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
b.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
```

This results in:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: I translated this to Java and it works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you put the code up on pastebin or something and I'll edit my question with the converted code?

Comment: I accepted your answer and added the Java code as an alternative. Keep the C# version as it might be useful for somebody.

Answer (score 0):

@Enigmativity's answer translated to Java

```
Observable<Integer> a0 = Observable.just(3, 4);
Observable<Integer> b0 = Observable.just(1, 2);
PublishSubject<Integer> a = PublishSubject.<Integer>create();
Observable<Integer> b = b0.finallyDo(() -> {
    a0.subscribe(a);
});
a.forEach(System.out::print);
b.forEach(System.out::print);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could subscribe b and then in the onComplete of observable b subscribe a. In both observable you have to implement on the onNext action the print of the emitted item.

```
    Observable<Integer> a = Observable.just(3, 4);
    Observable<Object> b = Observable.just(1, 2);
    b.subscribe(System.out::print, System.out::println, () -> a.subscribe(System.out::print));
```

Comment: for this I would need to change the way subscribers subscribe. As explained, I could not do that in my case. Thanks anyway.